# How to fix Excel VBA QueryTables not pulling data from a website

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have used this code in the past to pull data from ESPN for the rosters in my fantasy baseball league. I was able to get the rosters and put them all in one column in Excel. Then do some formatting. But now, data cannot be pulled. Nothing shows. ESPN did change their site to look different so I am inclined to think that effected how this code can work.

What I have tried changing in the code so far: change the ".WebSelectionType" for all three types (xlSpecifiedTables, xlAllTables, xlEntirepage); tried different .WebTables values.

-Will this ".QueryTable" command still work on this url? 
-Will I have to use a different command/code to scrape the table from this url?

```
Sheet11.Range("h:p").ClearContents  'clear old data
url = "URL;http://fantasy.espn.com/baseball/league/rosters?leagueId=101823"

With Sheet11.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    url, Destination:=Range("$h$1"))
    .Name = "MyESPNRoster"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebTables = "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14"    'the table number to get the right table of data. there should be 12 rosters
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = True
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @Zac  - I added the url.

Comment: I think you will need browser automation. What is the minimum info you need from the page?

Comment: @QHarr - I need the player names at the very least (i.e. the "player" column). Having the Team name, which is right above the slot/player/acq columns, is quite helpful too.

Comment: oh... are the team names like Draft Night Bday Buzz etc?

Comment: @QHarr - yes, team names are like "Draft Night Bday Buzz", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much all that info (I think a lot more actually) is available in a json response from their API. Below is an example for the teams and names. You need to use a [json parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas). After adding the `.bas` from the link supplied to your project, add the references shown below.

Add a standard module to your project by opening the VBE with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>, right click in project area and add module. Then paste code into module e.g. module 1.

In VBA Json structure the `[]` indicate collections accessed by index or For Each over. The `{}` are dictionaries accessed by key, everything else are string literals.

```
Option Explicit
'  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Public Sub GetPlayers()
    Dim json As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Cells.ClearContents

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/flb/seasons/2019/segments/0/leagues/101823?view=mSettings&view=mRoster&view=mTeam&view=modular&view=mNav", False
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
    End With

    Dim item As Object, nextItem As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    c = 0
    For Each item In json("teams")
        r = 1: c = c + 1
        ws.Cells(r, c) = item("location") & " " & item("nickname")
        For Each nextItem In item("roster")("entries")
            r = r + 1
            ws.Cells(r, c) = nextItem("playerPoolEntry")("player")("fullName")
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**Sample of json (1 player info):**

The following is only a small sample of all the info retrieved for each team player (too much to show it all)

[image]

---

**Sample of output:**

[image]

Comment: I am getting an error: run-time error '0', KeyNotFoundError, Dictionary key not found: completeDate.  When I press "Debug", it goes to "json_ParseObject.item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)" in the Private Functions section of the JSON parser module. 

When I Debug at this point, I get the following message: run-time error '10001': Error parsing JSON: 2882487218,"drafted": expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', null, true, false, '{', or '['.

Do you know why this may be happening?

Comment: For some reason  I didn't get see a notification of your message.

Comment: It still runs fine for me. Are you running the code exactly as shown in my answer?

Comment: I'm wondering if you have changed the code and are using invalid accessor  syntax

Comment: So I got this to work. I had to remove the "Selenium Type Library" from my references. But I use the Selenium references for some other modules. Can I use this code without disabling the Selenium reference? Or temporarily disable this reference before this code runs?

Comment: I'm unsure as it runs fine for me with selenium type library reference included.

Comment: You added the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference yes?

Comment: Yes, the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference is included. The only other one that is added compared to a new workbook is Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library.

Comment: That wouldn't cause the problem. Can you pastebin.com a link of the exact code you are running?

Comment: I got it to work with the Selenium type library. I turned it off then turned it back on. Now the code is working well. not sure why that did it, but it's working!