# vba - "Unable to open [api link]. The Internet site cannot return the object you request (HTTP/1.0 403)." Why is this API link not working in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

```
Sub __()

    'clear old data
    Range("B2:F100").ClearContents
    
    'get list of tickers
    For i = 2 To 100
        ticker = Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value
        
        If ticker <> "" Then
    
        'tickerstring = Right(tickerstring, Len(tickerstring) - 1)
            ticker = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=" & ticker & "&apikey=MYAPIKEY"
            
queryquote:
                With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & ticker, Destination:=Range("B" & i))
                    .BackgroundQuery = True
                    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
                    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
                End With
                
               'Text to Columns
                
        End If
    
    Next i
    
    Range("B2:B100").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True
    
    'import data
            
    

End Sub
```

I get this error:
[image: Error Message in Excel VBA]

I am new to VBA, Excel, and APIs in general. I have searched and searched the web but can't seem to find any solutions to my problem. I am not sure why I keep getting the error I do, and I'm not sure how to proceed. What is causing my program to fail?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Have you checked the contents of "ticker"? Is it **exactly** what the site expects?

Comment: Yes, actually I directly put in that link: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demokey. It worked fine. However, it _did_ return a json object.. Maybe therein lies the problem? I'm not sure because I'm very new to all this.

Comment: I don't think QueryTable will parse JSON, look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420364/how-to-fix-excel-vba-querytables-not-pulling-data-from-a-website)